# Importing data from xls,csv to Mysql using Yii 2.0 Framework

Tags: import, yii2, mysqlimport

I need to import data from XLS,CSV file into MySql database using YII 2.0 Framework,

XLS, CSV files contains datas which should to imported to one table in Mysql DB, Please provide any information to proceed.

Comment: I didn't try anything, i dont have idea at all, you have to help me pls

Comment: That's not how this site works unfortunately.

Comment: [Click here](http://yii.te.gd/wiki/336/importing-csv-file-to-mysql-table-using-load-data-command/) i tried this but i dont know how to do this in yii2

Comment: You can access dierctly to the mySql database ? What  about the application  architecture? Is local? is Remote? , is database accessible? You can use PHPAdmin or database management Tools? The link you provided is for Yii1 you are asking for Yii2.?...!? Explain your problem better

Comment: from application i want to import the excel sheet that must to store data in database, am using PHPmyAdmin,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope this will help

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Import();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

            if ( $model->file )
                {
                    $time = time();
                    $model->file->saveAs('csv/' .$time. '.' . $model->file->extension);
                    $model->file = 'csv/' .$time. '.' . $model->file->extension;

                     $handle = fopen($model->file, "r");
                     while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) 
                     {
                        $name = $fileop[0];
                        $age = $fileop[1];
                        $location = $fileop[2];
                        // print_r($fileop);exit();
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO details(name, age, location) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$location')";
                        $query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
                     }

                     if ($query) 
                     {
                        echo "data upload successfully";
                     }

                }

            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you ignore 1st row?

Comment: `new Import();` where did this came from?